# how to make the toolbar to overlap on the fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar

i've added toolbar on my fragment  :

myFragmentXml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="left|right">




    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/notesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>




</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and am trying to add a fade in AND fade out effect on my toolbar which can be trigger by scrollView see [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recycleview/master/screenshots/parallaxtoolbar.gif) for better understanding

but my toolbar is on top of the fragment (not covering the fragment)

here my toolbar's alpha is 0 (transparent) but i want the image to  be covered by toolbar but right now its below toolbar

[image: image1]

Comment: Change LinearLayout to FrameLayout

Or you can even remove LinearLayotu parent and not change to anything - Relativelayout, that you have in top should be enough, and there is no sense to nest views

Comment: @MateuszPryczkowski didnt work man , already tried with frame layout , RelativeLayout  , because now the image is on top of toolbar , the fragment is covering the toolbar

Comment: I forgot about reorder. Put Toolbar after SwipeRefreshLayout in xml file

Comment: Try this one;- http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: @MateuszPryczkowski didnt work everything is now toolbar is only visible (on the middle of screen )

Comment: Just to be sure, as top parent you have RelativeLayout, then inside of it you have SwipeRefreshLayout (with RecyclerView inside), and after it toolbar?
Probably not, as this what you say is rather not possible in this configuration

Comment: allright , so what should is do ? which kind of configuration  do i need ? i changed the top to CoordinatorLayout layout @MateuszPryczkowski

Comment: Depending, what you want to achieve:
1. if you want to learn , how to make things from base/core and do it by yourself, then just to solve issue with image having behind toolbar(and having base for next work) would be configuration, that I proposed - RelativeLayout in top(or even FrameLayout will be enough here), then inside both SwipeRefreshLayout first, and and after Toolbar.
2. if you want to use ready/checking workign solutions, just follow link from Adarsh:
http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: after getting pissed off , setting the elevation did the job  thanks MateuszPryczkowski  and @AdarshYadav for your effort appreciate you guys :D